# Add button programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints

I want to make a button appear when there are 1 or more characters in a text field.
Currently, I have 3 problems:

1. I can't use the @objc if I do that then I get the following error "@objc can only be used with members of classes, @objc protocols, and concrete extensions of classes".
   So basically I can't use the button.
2. I want to add constraints to the button, but on some of those I want the Safe Area to be the "toItem" but I don't know which "name" it has for that, I used view.safeAreaInsets but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it.
3. I want to check how many characters there are in a text field (so I want the button to appear the moment that the user types a letter).
   I would think it has to be done in an if statement but I don't know how to check for the characters in a text field.

This is my code for the first problem:

```
 addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)

 self.view.addSubview(addButton)
 @objc func buttonAction(_ : UIButton) {

 }
```

This is for the second one:

```
 let buttonRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .right, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view.safeAreaInsets, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)

 let buttonTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view.safeAreaInsets , attribute: .top , multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)
```

This is for the third one:

```
 if (TextFieldName.text!.count > 0) {


 }
```

This is my total code:

```
 import UIKit


 extension AddWorkoutController {
func hideKeyboard() {
    let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
 }
 class AddWorkoutController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var TextFieldName: UITextField!

let addButton   = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureTextFields()
    self.hideKeyboard()

    addButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Add-Button"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    addButton.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)

    let buttonRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .right, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view.safeAreaInsets, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)
    let buttonTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: view.safeAreaInsets , attribute: .top , multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)
    let buttonHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 32)
    let buttonWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: addButton, attribute: .width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64)



    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(addButton)
    self.view.addConstraints([buttonRightConstraint, buttonTopConstraint, buttonHeightConstraint, buttonWidthConstraint])

    @objc func buttonAction(_ : UIButton) {

    }

    if (TextFieldName.text!.count > 0) {


    }
}

private func configureTextFields () {
    TextFieldName.delegate = self
    }
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

 }




 extension UIViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
 }
```

Maybe it sounds like a stupid question but I'm a beginner.​

Answer (score -1):

1. `@objc func buttonAction(_ : UIButton)`
   is a function and she must be outside of viewDidLoad, at the same level

```
class AddWorkoutController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @objc func buttonAction(_ : UIButton) {

    }
}
```

2. For me the best solution is to add your `addButton` in the storyboard with hidden property checked by default (select your button and then go to right panel > Show the attributes inspector > hidden property)
3. You must add `func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)` in your `AddWorkoutController` extension. Inside you can add your `if (TextFieldName.text!.count > 0)` and then change `isHidden` property of `addButton` (`addButton.isHidden`)

```
extension AddWorkoutController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    }
}
```

PS: Be carefull of your indentation for more lisibility and in general variable are written in camelCase 
 You'll find some best practice here => https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide